# Reformatting code involving Lambda is extremely slow in Intellij IDEA 14.1.2

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda

When I practice implementing Promise-like network processing, I find the intellij  IDE becomes unresponsive when reformatting long code involving lambda expressions. Sometimes luckily it finished the reformatting job in several minutes, but most time it got stuck. 
How does it happen? and how to fix it?
Thanks:)

below is my code

```
Node myAddr = nodes.get(local);
    server = new TCPServer();
    server.bindAsync(myAddr.host, myAddr.port)
          .<ChannelFuture>then(future -> {
              if (log.isInfoEnabled())
                  log.info("local server has started @" + myAddr + " result=" + future.isSuccess());
              async.onEvent(future);
          })
          .<ConnectEvent>loop(conn -> {
              if (log.isInfoEnabled())
                  log.info(conn.channel.remoteAddress() + " connected to me");
              conn.asyncStream
                      .<NetworkEvent<ByteBuf>>then(id_event -> {//identification
                          ByteBufInputStream in = new ByteBufInputStream(id_event.msg);
                          int index = (int) serializer.deserialize(in);
                          if (log.isInfoEnabled())
                              log.info("identify " + id_event.ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + " is " + index);
                          if (!connections.containsKey(index) || !connections.get(index).accept(id_event.ctx.channel()))
                              id_event.ctx.close();
                      })
                      .<NetworkEvent<ByteBuf>>loop(msg_event -> {
                          if (log.isInfoEnabled())
                              log.info("recv msg from " + conn.channel.remoteAddress());
                          ByteBufInputStream in = new ByteBufInputStream(msg_event.msg);
                          async.onEvent(serializer.deserialize(in));
                          return true;
                      })
                      .exception((e) -> {
                          if (log.isErrorEnabled())
                              log.error("error: " + e.getMessage());
                      });
              return true;
          });
```

Comment: Could you please capture a CPU snapshot as described in https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-192 and file a YouTrack issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ with the snapshot attached?

Comment: I am trying to attach the CPU snapshot file, but it is too large (51.6MB) @yole

Comment: ok, issused successfully@yole